# Certificate error when using Chrome for iOS with company CA

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate, ios

I am using an iPad with Google Chrome installed to access the internet. I have downloaded and installed the Netbox Blue certificate authority [from their website](http://netboxblue.com/certs). I can currently access `https://` websites using Safari however I cannot access these sites using the Chrome app. I am not getting any certificate errors while using Safari.

Is there a particular way you need to add certificate authorities to the Chrome app, or is this an issue with my connection?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to add Certificate Authorities to Chrome.app on iOS. The only way to manage them is in `Settings > General > Profiles`.

It seems like this is an issue with Chrome.app that's not resolved yet. See [Chrome for iOS ignores trusted root CA certificate](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Jzq5lMNVPbc). You may get additional help by posting to the Google Chrome Forum (linked before).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply, but the easiest way to get this fixed that I have found is to remove all profiles by going into Settings > General > Profiles and removing all of the profiles that you don't know...

Hopefully it helps! :)