# iOS 8 - Apps other than Safari won't accept Cyberoam certificate

Tags: ios, certificate, ssl

My college network is secured with Cyberoam network. And Cyberoam requires a certificate it provides to be installed to access SSL secured websites. However, even after installing the certificate only Safari seems to be using the certificate and can open secure websites like Facebook. However other apps like Chrome, Facebook and Messenger won't work. I wonder why Chrome says **Invalid Certificate Authority** (see the screenshot below). The same certificate works well in PC.

I'm on iOS 8.1.4.

[image]

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is.

Comment: So, my concern here is that you are installing a CA certificate, which is really different than an SSL certificate.   A CA cert allows for all HTTPS traffic from your device to be decrypted.   This is why your apps aren't working...   many are designed to prevent traffic going through a CA cert, as anyone can now read the transmission.    Are you sure there isn't an SSL cert you are supposed to be installing instead?

Comment: Here's some more info regarding the Cyberoam CA cert...   https://blog.torproject.org/category/tags/ca-certificates

Comment: And here...   https://media.torproject.org/misc/2012-07-03-cyberoam-CVE-2012-3372.txt

Comment: I would seriously stay away from installing ANY type of CA certificate on a phone.   As someone who DOES install CA certs on phones specifically for the purpose of capturing HTTPS traffic (a special kind of testing I do for mobile apps), I can ensure you that all of your passwords / app data / etc are being sent via plaintext once you have the CA installed.

Comment: @Charlie74 The same certificate works on desktop browsers and I can it working on Android devices as well. In the case of iOS itself, Safari seems to be accepting the certificate. This is the certificate issued by my institute at least.

Answer (score 1):

I found this: [Certificate error when using Chrome for iOS with company CA](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103157/certificate-error-when-using-chrome-for-ios-with-company-ca/103338#103338)

> There is no way to add Certificate Authorities to Chrome.app on iOS.
>   The only way to manage them is in Settings > General > Profiles.
>
> It seems like this is an issue with Chrome.app that's not resolved
>   yet. See Chrome for iOS ignores trusted root CA certificate. You may
>   get additional help by posting to the Google Chrome Forum (linked
>   before).

Comment: This problem applies to apps other than Chrome as well, Facebook and Messenger to name a few. Only Safari seems to be accepting the certificate.